# Pasar variable polinomio por parámetro a una función

Tags: c

Quiero resolver un polinomio en C y tengo este código, supongo que se podrá hacer de otra manera pero esto es muy básico. Quiero pasar un polinomio por parámetro a la función `resultado` para que me devuelva un valor pero no sé como hacerlo. ¿Cómo sería?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int resultado(float polinomio[], int y);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int x, y, z, t, i;
  float resul;
  float polinomio[15];

  //3.5x^4+2x^3+2.25
  polinomio[0] = 2.25;
  polinomio[1] = 0;
  polinomio[2] = 0;
  polinomio[3] = 2;
  polinomio[4] = 3.5;

  printf("Elige si va a derivar u obtener \n ");
  printf("1 -- Derivar \n");
  printf("2 -- Obtener \n");

  scanf("%d", &x);

  switch (x) {
    case 1:
      printf("Introduzca el valor de X");
      scanf("%d", &y);
      resul = resultado(polinomio[i], y);
      printf("El valor obtenido es %f ", resul);
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("La derivada es ");
  }

  return 0;
}


int resultado(float polinomio[], int y) {
  int x, r, z, t, w, p, i;
  x = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x = x + polinomio[i] * pow(y, i);

    i++;
  }

  return x;

}
```

Comment: `resul = resultado(polinomio,y);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar un array a una función has de pasar la dirección del primer elemento:

```
resul = resultado(&polinomio[0], y);
```

`polinomio[0]` es el primer elmento y `&polinomio[0]` es la dirección de ese primer elemento. El operador `&` devuelve un puntero con la dirección a lo que le sigue.

Obtener un puntero al primer elemento de un array es una operación tan común que hay una forma abreviada de hacerlo en C, pon el array sin especificar ningún elemento:

```
resul = resultado(polinomio, y);
```

Tal que así tu programa funcionaría. Pero hay un detalle más a tener en cuenta a la hora de pasar un array. ¿Qué tamaño tiene el array? En tu ejemplo tiene tamaño 5 fijo, pero lo normal es que quieras una función que funciona con arrays de cualquier tamaño. Para eso lo normal es poner otro parámetro extra con el tamaño. En este cáso en vez del tamaño del array voy a poner el grado del polinomio, que queda más funcional. La función resultado quedará tal que asi:

```
int resultado(float polinomio[], int grado, int y) {
  int x, r, z, t, w, p, i;
  x = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= grado; i++) {
    x = x + polinomio[i] * pow(y, i);
  }

  return x;
}
```

Con ese pequeño cambio tu función `resultado` pasa a ser de propósito general y puede calcular cualquier polinomio, no solo de grado 4. La invocarías tal que así:

```
resul = resultado(polinomio, y);
```

Fíjate además que he quitado la línea con `i++`. El bucle for ya hace esto. Poner esa línea hace que `i` se incremente dos veces en cada iteración del bucle, lo que lleva a no sumar los exponentes impares y optener un resultado incorrecto.

Por último, yo cambiaría el tipo de datos que usas en los cálculos. Usar `float` en vez de `int`. Con polinomios de grado 4 es fácil exceder el máximo valor que cabe en un `int`. Un float permite valores más grandes a costa de perder precisión. Y, si trabajas con valores de `y` pequeños también es mejor un `float` puesto que un `int`  no permite valores entre 0 y 1 mientras que un `float` permite muchos. Si se queda corto un `float` puedes usar un `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para enviar como parametro un arreglo solo debes enviar la variable no un elemento, cambia esta linea:

```
resul = resultado(polinomio[i], y);
// por:
resul = resultado(polinomio, y);
```